# Cancel touch events for other views

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, touches

I have a `UIView` `subclass` that displays some content on top of `camera preview` (`AR`, but not `ARKit`). In this view I use `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` to detect if user has pressed on displayed objects. Now I have this view `embedded` in `controller` inside `UINavigationController` and this `NavigationController` has enabled showing/hiding bars on tap. I would like to make so that if I detect tapping on object inside `ARView`, then I can perform some action, but then touches are not received by `NavigationController`, so that bars are hiding only if I tap on background. How can I block sending touch events further in such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, if I understood you correctly, you want to recognize both events, and call methods of both gestures, right? If so, try this code snippet:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This method allows to recognize several gestures

Comment: Well not always. For now it already works that way - I get both detected touchesEnded in my subview and also Bars on navigation controller are hiding. I want to be able to somehow block these bars to hide if my subview touch was on special place of subview. I didn't implement NavigationController touches, these are done by SDK, I just selected some options in storyboard. In summary I want to be able to limit touches to only my subview but not always - only if I decide so after touches are detected. Also I don't use GestureRecognizers, just touchesBegan and touchesEnded.

Comment: Actually I think that I could redesign my code to use gesture recognizer, and then this might work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you desire to limit touches on different views, you can change the property of `userInteractionEnabled`on each condition you like.

When this property is set to false, no touch events will be received for selected views.